# No encuentra la libreria dll del proyecto.Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Necesito de su apoyo por favor,tengo un problema con un proyecto, que anteriormente lo publicaba de una pc pero se malogró la pc.
Ahora tengo un error que cuando ejecuto el proyecto me sale el siguiente error :

> Server Error in '/Demo' Application. 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ad1w31qe2q1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Por mas que el dll está en el proyecto, lo quito y lo vuelvo a poner con la ayuda del visual studio 2012. pero igual me sale que no lo encuentra.
En la web.config lo quito y lo vuelvo a llamar igual tampoco funciona.

Lo pusé en otro pc y funciona pero lo publico al servidor de prueba y tengo la misma falla.

He estado buscando pero no encuentro la solución, la unico mas cercano es que lo agregue en windows/assembly de mi maquina y servidor, pero en el servidor de prueba sigue funcionando el codigo antiguo asi que supongo que no es eso.¿que me recomienda por hacer, por favor?

Es un proyecto WebForm asp.net

Comment: Hola. Aquí hay información [Using the stand-alone IBM MQ .NET client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Aquí comentan algo parecido:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109743/issue-with-debugging-app-using-mq-websphere-amqmdnet-dll-due-to-version-confli

En esencia, recomienda reinstalar MQ Client version, en tu caso la versión 7.5.